# autocomplete edit form with jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a problem when working with jquery and form.
example, 1 have some patient edit form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="patient_medic_record_number">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="address">
    <select name="sex">
        <option value="--SEX--">
        <option value="Male">
        <option value="Female">
     </select>
</form>
```

how to load data from mysql database then autocomplete name,address,sex when i insert the patient_medic_record_number.

Comment: Well you have long way to go. My suggestion is to start with jquery basics, DOM operations.

Comment: jQuery Autocomplete might be helpful. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok dude , you can use JQuery [Ajax Method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to load the datas.

When you enter the **patient_medic_record_number** you must use its OnChange event to raise you XMLhttpRequest like this :

```
$("input[name=patient_medic_record_number]").change(function(){

      var num = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "YourPage.aspx/FillControl",
                data: "{ 'id': '" + num + "' }",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#input[name=name]").val(data.d[0]);
                    $("#input[name=address]").val(data.d[1]);
                    $("#input[name=sex]").val(data.d[2]);

            });
        });

});
```

and then use this web method in your code behind to return JSON values :

```
[WebMethod]
public static object[] FillControl(string id)
{

     //Do something with id and etc

     return new object[]{"Ali foroughi" , "No where" , "Male"};

}
```

If you want for more details comment me.

Comment: Ali => please give me the jquery code to send and display data to name,address and sex field...

Comment: @DedyBlackLaBeneamata , I did it